# Saved SharedPreferences while Application is not using

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to save a sharedpreference when the application received sms like 'ON'.
But then, when the device receive the sms 'ON' while I'm not using it, I've got a dialog box caption application stopped. But when I remove the sharedprefences inside the method the toast message appear so it execute the method. I think there's a problem with sharedpreferences inside that method. Please help. Thanks.

here is some code from the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{ 
      static SharedPreferenceas sp; 

      public static void SPlron(Context context, Intent intent){ 
            Editor edit = sp.edit(); 
            edit.putString("a", "ON"); 
            edit.commit(); 
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show 
      } 
}
```

and i got this error in logcat

> Tag: trace Text: error opening trace file: No such file or directory
>   (2)

Comment: Post some code please and your logcat too.

Comment: and post the error log.

Comment: The MainActivity.java includes:

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

static SharedPreferenceas sp;

public static void SPlron(Context context, Intent intent){
 Editor edit = sp.edit();
 edit.putString("a", "ON");
 edit.commit();
 Toast.makeText(context, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show
}
}

Comment: The logcat first error contains: 
Tag: trace Text: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: I think you dont initialize sharedpreference if app gets a sms. just add sp=context.getSharedPreference("SMS",0) in first line of SPIron

Comment: @Adem you are right. After posting Answer I saw your comment. Hope from the code Jobelle get more idea.

Comment: @Jobelle if you have solved the issue kindly update here

Comment: Thank you @Adem. You're right! I don't put initial value to my static method  sp = context.getSharedPreferences("SMS", 0); that's why when the static method called, the application forced closed because the initial value that I put on onCreate is never be used because onCreate method is not executed when application is not using. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When your `SPlron()` method is called at that time might be `SharedPreferences` is not initialized. try the below code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        SharedPreferences preferences;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        public  void SPlron(Context context, Intent intent){
            preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("a", "ON");
            editor.commit();
            Log.d("Saved!","Saved");
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
}
```

Let me know if more help required.